# Как удалить все изменения после выполнения данных команд (всё что с ними связано и скачалось-установилось, и тп.)?

Tags: mysql, linux, сервер, centos7, консоль

```
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-7.noarch.rpm
yum -y localinstall mysql57-community-release-el6-7.noarch.rpm
```

По ошибке выполнены  команды для баз версии 5.7 как на Centos 6, хотя на самом деле машина на  ОС Centos 7 (и для неё есть другая команда). Все расположения по умолчанию.

Comment: **все** изменения вернуть назад теоретически можно, но это может потребовать нескольких часов довольно напряжённого и **квалифицированного** труда (причём никакой гарантии, что будет возвращено именно **всё**). раз вам нужна версия 5.7, но из другого пакета, так проще будет поставить этот пакет. 1. это быстро. 2. это может сделать даже условная «мартышка с инструкцией с левого сайта».

Comment: перед копипаста, желательно, просмотреть и прекинуть куда приведет исполнение команд. **rpm -qlp package.rpm** - покажет файлы пакета, можно удалить вручную или **rpm -r package.rpm**

Comment: У Баракина снова зашквар, какие часы? Это вообще о чём?  Пакет удаляется одной командой, потом можно пройтись и удалить осиротевшие и неиспользуемые библиотеки. Был специальный скрипт из yum-utils или как они там сейчас называются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если правильно вас понял, вы хотите отменить последнюю транзакцию yum.
Вывести список транзакций yum можно командой :

```
yum history list
```

Просмотрев все транзакции, выбираем подходящий id, например 746
Выполняем команду, она отобразит информацию об определённой транзакции:

```
yum history info id
```

отменяем транзакцию командой:

```
yum history undo id
```